# проблема с $or оператором

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Я пытаюсь написать небольшое приложение с помощью meteor.js и столкнулся с проблемой.
Я хочу сделать поиск в нескольких полях документов mongodb, но что-то идет не так.
Ниже мой код.

`search_query` - вводимый пользователем текст

```
var reg = new RegExp(search_query);
if (search_query) {
    console.log(search_query, reg);
    return Pulsedb.find({
        description: reg
    }, {
        limit: limit
    });
}
```

Такая конструкция работает и находит документы, в поле description которых есть искомое значние. Однако мне нужно сделать проверку наличия совпадений в нескольких полях. Я пробую

```
if (search_query) {
    console.log(search_query, reg);
    return Pulsedb.find({
        $or: {
            description: reg,
            prerec: reg,
            name: reg,
            type: reg
        }
    }, {
        limit: limit
    });
}
```

Я рассчитываю найти документы, хотя бы в одном поле которых есть совпадение с запросом.
Но в результате запрос выдает мне вообще все имеющиеся в базе данные.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в `$or`. Нужно так

```
 $or: [{ description: reg}, {prerec: reg}, {name: reg}, {type: reg}]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Ошибка была действительно именно тут.